# Unable to see preview image in fileupload component with AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

I'm using a fileupload component to render an image as part of the page in the initial creation dialog.

```
<image
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"
        cq-msm-lockable="jcr:file"
        autoStart="{Boolean}false"
        class="cq-droptarget"
        fieldLabel="Hero Image (large)"
        fileNameParameter="./image/fileName"
        fileReferenceParameter="./asset"
        mimeTypes="[image]"
        multiple="{Boolean}false"
        name="./image/file"
        title="Upload Image Asset"
        uploadUrl="${suffix.path}/image/file"
        useHTML5="{Boolean}true"/>
```

I've tried multiple variations of the uploadUrl | fileNameParameter | fileReferenceParameter and name fields without being able to see a preview image in the properties dialog.

[Screenshot of the broken preview block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhuSn.png)

I do see the image data in the CRXDE however. 
[jcr:content with image data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fUn2.png)

Does anyone have a working implementation of the fileupload in dialog they could share? This is with AEM 6.2.

Comment: Did you have a look at your browsers developer tools? Especially the error console. Because the image might be blocked for certain reasons. For example: the dispatcher could be misconfigured and block requests to the asset.

Comment: @Jens Returning a 404 Not Found error, is it still possible dispatcher would be blocking requests? -> I would expect a different error in this case.

Comment: 404 is the expected error if dispatcher has blocked and image if your are following standard configuration of allow/disallow on paths. Disallow would return 404.

Comment: Try accessing the instance directly, by specifying the port and IP address, you'll go around the dispatcher. Make sure you even have one set up in front of your Author instance.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz Currently not using the dispatcher at all, accesing the site via 4502.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so this ended up being a little more complicated than what I had hoped was a simple configuration change. All credit goes to [@alex-figliolia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4772077/alex-figliolia) whom figured this out.

```
<file
        autoStart="{Boolean}false"
        class="cq-droptarget"
        fieldLabel="Hero Image (large)"
        fileNameParameter="./image/fileName"
        fileReferenceParameter="./image/fileReference"
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        mimeTypes="[image]"
        multiple="{Boolean}false"
        name="./image/file"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"
        title="Upload Image Asset"
        uploadUrl="${suffix.path}"
        useHTML5="{Boolean}true"
        />
```

The corrected dialog, has ./image/fileReference.

In the content.xml (jcr:root) for the component we add a default image with a sling:resourceType of image.

```
<cq:template
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <image
        sling:resourceType="wcm/foundation/components/image"
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        text="image"/>
</cq:template>
```

In this instance we are using the use-api and js files to get the data needed. Theres a ret object I am not displaying. But its a simple javascript object where ret.image starts as null.

```
var image = currentNode.hasNode('image') ? currentNode.getNode('image') : null;

if (image) {
   ret.image = image.hasProperty('fileReference') ? image.getProperty('fileReference') : null;
}

if (!ret.image) {
    try {
        var res = image.hasNode("file") ? image.getNode("file") : null;
        ret.image = res.getPath();
        ret.image = "background-image: url("+ ret.image + ");";
    } catch(err) {
        ret.image = "background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150x150?text=Placeholder);";
    }
} else {
   ret.image = "background-image: url(" + ret.image + ");";
}
```

And that's it, this will allow draggable or uploaded files to display their preview and their correct image.

For completeness here is the HTML used as well where data is the return value from the javascript.

```
<div class="${data.imagesize} ${data.imageBackgroundColor ? 'icon' : ''}" style="${data.image @ context='styleString'}"></div>
```